# What does connect action do in iOS development?

Tags: ios, xcode, oop, swift

[image: Connect Action in Xcode 6]

I am writing code for a tip calculator in Xcode using swift. I am reading a book and was instructed to connect the slider to the calculateTip method. I am trying to figure out what connecting the action will do. Does this simply mean that every time the slider is moved the calculateTip method will be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular connection means that you assign an **action** to the slider: In this case your `calculateTip` method. By default the slider sends a message to this method, when its value has changed. This connection can also be done programmatically, but Xcode makes that easier for you.

So to answer your question: yes. Anytime the slider is moved the calculateTip method is called. **But** take a look on the sliders `continuous`property to decide whether this method should be called when the user stops dragging the slider, or — as the name suggests — to send continuous messages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it depends which action you choose exactly, but if you select the `ValueChanged` action then yes, it will call that method every time the slider moves.